# How to assess whether a predictor variable is linearly related to the response variable once the other variables have been included in the model?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

Just like the title says "How to assess whether a predictor variable is linearly related to the response variable once the other variables have been included in the model?"

EDIT: Adding ANOVA printout from R if that helps. I'm trying to assess whether X7 and X8 are linearly related to Y once the other variables have been included in the model.

`Response: Y
    Df  SumSq   MeanSq  F-value   Pr(>F)
x1   1  66.202  66.202  150.266 < 2.2e-16   ***
x2   1  74.665  74.665  169.474 < 2.2e-16   ***
x3   1  24.952  24.952  56.6354   5.652e-12 ***
x4   1  26.017  26.017  59.0526   2.365e-12 ***
x5   1  14.837  14.837  33.6763   4.117e-08 ***
x6   1  11.162  11.162  25.3365   1.445e-06 ***
x7   1   0.796   0.796   1.8063   0.1811
x8   1   0.350   0.350   0.7941   0.3744
Res 141 62.120 0.441`

Comment: Because the test you propose is *not* a test of a linear relationship (as ordinarily understood), could you elaborate on what you mean by "linearly related"?

Comment: okay maybe that's why I am not understanding what my colleague is explaining. Sorry I am not fully introduced with MLR. Disregard my test, what is a test of linear relationship between the variables?

Comment: I suggest visual inspection of the new predictor variable vs. the existing model errors - it is possible this might reveal something obvious, and is certainly easy to do.

Comment: I made an ANOVA table in R and it is clear to see that the new variables are not nearly as significant as the p-values are .3744 and .1811 while the others are all well below .000001. My colleague is talking about there being an actual test statistic and separate p-value for testing the linear relationship between these two new variables and the response variable. Maybe I am just completely misunderstanding everything he is saying though

Comment: Significance of a term in a linear regression is no indication of a "linear relationship."  The latter refers to the idea that the response $Y$ really does seem to vary as $a + bX$ for a regressor $X.$ This is tested with a "goodness of fit" test.  The basic idea behind most such GoF tests is to enhance the original model to allow $Y$ to behave in a distinctly non-linear way with respect to $X$ and see whether that appreciably improves the model. So my question to you is whether this is what you are asking about or if you're just asking about significance of the variable in the model.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for the much needed clarification. What is a good example of a GoF test suitable for my example? a chi-squared test perhaps?